# The google-services.json file oauth section that I download is different from the one in my app

Tags: android, google-play-services

so I'm working on an app that has existed for some years and I'm having some issues with Firebase. Some advice I've gotten is downloading a new google-services.json file from the console.
I've done that but this file is more different from my current file than I was expecting and I don't feel comfortable switching it out.

The *biggest changes* have happened to the **oauth_client** where for each client 1 oauth client has been removed. This oauth client always had: **client_id, client_type** and **android_info** which further contained a **package_name** and **certificate_hash**.

*Now* my remaining **oauth clients** only have a **client_id** and **client_type**.

Does anyone know why that client with more info got removed? Is this something that used to be present in the config file and has now been removed? Or could it be that maybe someone did something in the app along the line where this client was no longer necessary?

I'd like to understand the info in the config file, but if no one can explain it to me I'd settle for knowing if I can always trust the console to have an accurate config file or if I should keep the one we've been using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke directly to support at google and they didn't explain the differences to me but they did confirm that the config file in the console is always the correct one.
And wouldn't you know, using it resolved my issues.